# How to Unit test the logging in Java springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

Hi I'm new to java Spring boot. Currently I'm working on a java application and I was asked to write unit testing for the service layer. However when I checked with the JaCoCo code coverage it shows that the below logging statements are not covered from the unit testing. So how Can I write unit test for logging? Is it a must to write unit test for loggings?

Can anyone please help me with this matter?
Here I have attached the uncovered logging statement.

[image]

Comment: Is it really necessary to cover this part of code by a test? --- If it is, then apply the [Inversion of Control principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control): make the logger injectable, mock it, verify the call on the mock. I wrote a [kata](https://bitbucket.org/turing85/loggerunittestkata/src/master/) for this exact use case some time ago.

Comment: Personally I would just test that the exception is thrown, and not test the logging.